# How to generate HTML with jquery clone with different names?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, clone

I have HTML like this:

```
<div id='main'>

   <div id='child-0'>
     <input type='text' name='data[0][name]'>
     <input type='text' name='data[0][dob]'>
     <input type='text' name='data[0][location]'>
   </div>

</div>

<input type='button' id='add' value='Add'>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("input#add").live( 'click', function(){
   $("#main").append("<br />");
   $("#child-0").clone(false).appendTo( $("#main") );
});
```

[Above code is working but it is creating elements with same name](http://jsfiddle.net/4u6qD/). I want to generate it something like this:

```
<div id='main'>

   <div id='child-0'>
     <input type='text' name='data[0][name]'>
     <input type='text' name='data[0][dob]'>
     <input type='text' name='data[0][location]'>
   </div>

   <div id='child-1'>
     <input type='text' name='data[1][name]'>
     <input type='text' name='data[1][dob]'>
     <input type='text' name='data[1][location]'>
   </div>

</div>
```

What is the simple solution.

Thanks

Comment: where is `<input type='file'>`?

Comment: Sorry for misleading title. Stackoverflow now saves your last edits and I forgot to change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("input#add").live( 'click', function(){
    $("#main").append("<br />");
    var cloned = $("#main div:last").clone(false).appendTo( $("#main") );
    cloned.find('[name^=data]').attr('name', function() {
        var index = this.name.match(/\[(\d)\]/);
        if (index != null && index.length > 1) {
            var newIndex = parseInt(index[1], 10) + 1; 
            return this.name.replace(/\[(\d)\]/, '[' + newIndex + ']');
        }
        return this.name;    
    });
});​
```

Comment: Thanks for response but it is creating all new elements with array index 1(`data[1][name]`): http://jsfiddle.net/4u6qD/4/

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in my selector. I have updated the answer now:  http://jsfiddle.net/NLaJA/